# Modify excel spreadsheet using jxl on Android

Tags: java, android, excel, jxl

I'm developing an Android App for filling a excel pre-formatted spreadsheet, using jxl. My issue is when i'm using the code for modifying cells according to the tutorial:

```
        WritableCell cell = sheet0.getWritableCell(0,8);
        if (cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL) 
        { 
          Label l = (Label) cell; 
          l.setString("hi"); 
        }
```

It doesn't appear anything on the spreadsheet. Even the the cell if the document is formatted for text, still doesn't work. I've attempted to write a number using:

```
        WritableCell cell = sheet0.getWritableCell(0,8);
        if (cell.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) 
        { 
          Number l = (Number) cell; 
          l.setValue(1); 
        }
```

and format the cell on the document as a number type, and still doesn't work. The only way that i can write on the document is by using the addCell method:

`Label label2 = new Label(0, 8, "X");
sheet0.addCell(label2);`

But in this way, the system will just add a new cell, not modifying the content, and losing the original format (the most critical for me is the borders style).

Please advise.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and I ended up solving it like this:

```
Cell existingCell = worksheet.getCell(columnIndex, rowIndex);
Label label = new Label(columnIndex, rowIndex, "some string");
label.setCellFormat(existingCell.getCellFormat());
worksheet.addCell(label);
```